# How to cover wth unit tests StreamWriter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, design-patterns

How to test the next code sample?

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(requestBody, Encoding.ASCII))
{
       ipnContext.RequestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The very first idea comes to my mind just create custom wrapper around StreamReader and inject it to class where it's needed. What do you thinks of it. Maybe you could give me more best solution.
Thanks for your attention

Comment: Maybe the question should be: What do you test?

Comment: If you didn't wand to suggest idea then skip this post and move ahead. I just want to get to know from more gurus how it applied on practices

Comment: My test read stem from Request . I need somehow create mock of streamReader

Comment: You can not cover those lines without wrapping it with an interface or "mockable" method. You are creating instance with "new" keyword in code and you can not intercept behavior of it. May be you can write a wrapper for StreamReader or move that functionality to another method and mock it in your tests.

Comment: Why would you need to mock StreamReader? What type is `requestBody`? Maybe that's what needs to be mocked..?

Comment: requestBody is Stream type

Comment: Then @KennethK.was spot on. You need to explain what you're actually trying to test. On the surface, it would seem you could use a MemoryStream, populated in whatever fashion makes sense, and just let the StreamReader do what it does.

Comment: The best way to write/arrange a unit test is that every third party dependency should be mocked. However, there are always a scenario where things don't go direction which one want to do. One of the suggestion which can be used here 1) Wrap to another class and inject the interface into actual code, the unit test should create the mock and inject it. 2) Use Shims (Fakes )- Read it here --https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: @KennethK.'s comment is valid - it's not clear from what you've asked what you intend to test. The only thing that's obvious from the minimal context you've supplied is that your code is strongly coupled to `StreamReader`, and it's reasonable for everyone to assume you do _not_ intend to test the implementation of `StreamReader`.